# Ranking each row to create mask dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, ranking

Sample dataframe `df` is defined as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(10*(2+np.random.randn(500, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
```

Within each row rank the top 5 columns and mark them as `1` and rest as `nan`.
`df` looked like

```
df.head()
           A          B          C          D          E          F          G          H
0   6.598436  44.318800  18.064752  13.418329  17.145434   6.696975  14.757765   8.797826
1   3.593140  14.571717  16.292330  28.390669  35.289606  -4.273124  20.519388  25.137833
2  36.777253  34.360523  28.020462  15.356690  22.038938  14.960303  15.225555  34.691981
3  18.623122  27.184421  -5.320215  31.694895  21.156375   9.947077  20.257575  21.035659
4  11.864725  30.458160  13.509029  27.037195  20.581043  25.371691   1.094735  28.703618
```

Desired output is:

```
df_output.head()
      A    B    C    D    E     F    G    H
0   nan    1    1    1    1   nan    1  nan
1   nan  nan    1    1    1   nan    1    1
2     1    1    1  nan    1   nan  nan    1
3   nan    1  nan    1    1   nan    1    1
4   nan    1  nan    1    1     1  nan    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_output = df.rank(1, ascending=False, method='first')
df_output[df_output > 5] = np.nan
df_output[df_output <= 5] = 1.0
```